# My laravel 5.6 project is opening on localhost but not on php artisan serve cmd

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8, php-5.6

I have copied laravel 5.6 project from friend's PC. It is running well on his PC but not on mine.
When I run `php artisan serve` command in cmd it gives me the error in cmd(screenshot attached).[cmd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5TsK.jpg)

It opens on localhost/tailorMS well:[localhost screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKiNt.jpg)

Other projects of laravel versions 7 and 8 open without any problem on cmd.
my **AppServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        if( (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
        //setting language
        if(isset($_COOKIE['language'])) {
            \App::setLocale($_COOKIE['language']);
        } else {
            \App::setLocale('en');
        }
        //get general setting value        
        $general_setting = DB::table('general_settings')->latest()->first();
        View::share('general_setting', $general_setting);
        config(['staff_access' => $general_setting->staff_access, 'date_format' => $general_setting->date_format, 'currency' => $general_setting->currency, 'currency_position' => $general_setting->currency_position]);
        
        $alert_product = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', true)->whereColumn('alert_quantity', '>', 'qty')->count();
        View::share('alert_product', $alert_product);
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe something related with PHP version, such things like that? Just for the diff of versions

Comment: I have php 7.4.3 version but I don' know about in which version it made

Comment: just remove those lines. Or add an exception for CLI calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the condition to detect if it's a CLI call, so no need to check for port

```
if(strpos(php_sapi_name(), 'cli') === false && ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Comment: It worked.Thanks man @N69S . But it loads only html, not with bootstrap css styles. on `localhost/tailorMS` it loads with full css styles

Comment: npm install && npm run dev to load assets